# what countByKey in JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a JavaPairRDD named 'pair' and want to count the number of times a key occurs (I think the JavaPairRDD is not like a HashMap and will have keys repeated, am I right ?). The countByKey function returns an Object, instead of a Long. So Doesn't it return the count ? Or what is the Object returned, and can we find the count from it ?

Answer (score 1):

`JavaPairRDD.countByKey()` returns a `Map` and the values are in fact the counts. Java has a bit of trouble with type inference in Spark (it's much, much better in Scala!), so you need to explicitly cast the values from `Object` to `Long`.

Comment: ok, hopefully they would convert it to Long , because there seems no explanations to have an Object here. As the function says, it is always a count - which is pure number. Anyways, thanks :)